# Confused on Floyd-Warshall's basic premise

Tags: algorithm

So I'm trying to understand the Floyd-Warshall algorithm and while I can implement it and clearly see it *does* work, I'm not entirely sure *why* it works because of one thing:

Since for each pair of vertices we check if some two other pairs of vertices allow us to have a shorter path between the pair we're currently processing and in the beginning we only know the distances from the vertices to themselves (which are all 0) and the distances with no intermediate vertices (which are our input), how can we be sure that the vertices we process first will be given the "true" shortest paths? I mean - when processing the first few vertices pairs, all we know is the input and some infinities so why is it guaranteed that it's enough to find the shortest paths and somewhere down the road we won't find something more profitable which could have been used in the vertices in the beginning?

Comment: Not sure I am following, you CAN find a shorter path somewhere along the way, and you will relax it, for example `V={a,b,c}`, `E={(a,b,100),(a,c,4),(c,b,1)}`. You will first find the path `(a,b,100)`, and only later will relax it to `(a,b,5)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the idea is that at each stage i the algorithm finds the shortest path between each pair of vertices with the restriction that the path can only use vertices 1..i

The trick is in the induction step.

Consider the shortest path a->b with the restriction that it only uses vertices 1..i

There are two cases, either the path goes via i, or it does not.

If it does not, then the shortest path is unchanged from the previous round.

If it does go via i, then the path must be of the form a->i->b and the total cost is the distance a->i plus the distance i->b, where each of these distances are valid from the previous round.

Another way of looking at this is to note that during the algorithm the distances between a particular pair of nodes (e.g. 1 and 2) will gradually reduce as better paths are found.  Initially the distance will be the direct distance 1->2, but if there is a better path such as 1->10->2, this will be found at stage 10 of the algorithm.

This feels like we may go wrong because we use the distance 1->2 at multiple points and it feels like we may use the wrong value.  However, perhaps it is clearer if you remember that at each stage we have found the exact answer for the question "What is the shortest path between 1 and 2, with the restriction that we can only use vertices 1..i"

Comment: Yes, of course I understand that but what I meant was how can we be sure that for every pair the best path (if it's different from the one we have now) has to be among the other ones which values we know at that moment. That's why I gave the example of the first few vertices we process: we have very limited data so how can we be sure that we'll find the shortest distance by some combination of the states we currently know if there's still so many infinities which may later turn out to be something really short and thus even more profitable for the pair of vertices we thought we'd processed?

Comment: Oh, now I've seen your edit (the last paragraph). Yes, it certainly helps a lot cause I somehow overlooked the fact! Still, how can we be sure that we won't find something better along the way? I mean - when checking the distance knowing that we'll only get the answer under the condition that we're using some vertex from a {1,...,i} subset, why are we sure that among these vertices aren't some INF paths that later turn out not only not to be INF but also cheap?

Comment: If I think about it from the perspective of repeatedly relaxing edges then I agree it seems very mysterious that it should work (and indeed many other orderings would fail).  However, I find that it makes more sense if I think about it as a dynamic programming approach to finding all n^3 answers to the question of "shortest path between pairs only using vertices 1..i"

Comment: I see. Still the concept of finding the n^3 answers is curious to me as well cause even then, we may choose such {1,...,i} subset that a large portion of it are unknown infinities, right? Or maybe that's just a part I should try to take on faith if I don't get it intuitively? :)

Comment: I agree that a large portion can be infinity - but I would not think of these as "unknown".  If a number is infinite, then that just means that we know for certain that there is no path between the pair that only goes through vertices 1,2,..,i.

Comment: Mhm, that makes perfect sense. Thank you a lot for the thorough explanation :)